# How do i get a responsive Header Image above the nav bar in Purity III - Corporate?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, templates, t3-framework

I am building a website for a project i have to do and i am stuck on that problem. Good guy Joomlart hides every answer behind a paywall, so i am pretty alone. ( i didn't realize the non existent community help only after starting with purity iii)

So i just want to add a position over the navbar and make it responsive so i can add a header image in there.

I use the Purity III - Corporate Template.

How do i do it? I am a bloody rookie :/

[image: what i mean]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add your new position in /templates/purity_iii/**templateDetails.xml**, inside the positions block:

```
<positions>
    <position>new-position</position>
</position>
```

Now add your position **in one** of this two options:

- /templates/purity_iii/**tpls/corporate.php**
- /templates/purity_iii/**tpls/blocks/header.php**

For the second option add this code **above the main navigation**:

```
<section class="new-position-css">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php $this->_p('new-position') ?>" style="none" />
</section>
```

From here add your custom module, for example a Custom HTML module with your image.

---

*Note:* By default the navigation **is fixed at the top**, change this code:

```
<!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
<header id="t3-mainnav" class="wrap navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top t3-mainnav">
```

To this:

```
<!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
<header id="t3-mainnav" class="wrap navbar navbar-default t3-mainnav">
```

---

As a final step, you can use *Firebug* for inspect the source code of your page in the browser, for example, add this rules in your main or [custom.css](http://www.t3-framework.org/documentation/bs3-customization#custom-css) file.

```
body {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.new-position-css p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.new-position-css img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Custom Position - Purity III]

To complement, find more info here: [Purity III Docs.](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/joomla-templates/purity-iii) & [T3 Docs.](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/joomla-framework/t3-framework-for-joomla-2-5-and-joomla-3)

Regards.

Comment: I tank you VERY MUCH, it worked on the first try and after a few css changes it looks pretty decent.
Again, thank you very much, you helped me a lot!