# How to make a header image above the navigation bar in Purity III fixed and/or how to attach the nav menu to it?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, t3-framework, purity-iii

I've been following the advice on how to put a header image above the nav bar in Purity-III given in https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16321/
I managed to reproduce the solution however what I really need is to use my image as a background for the navigation menu or the menu should be immediately below the image and both should be fixed. Because the image replaces the logo in the navigation bar I also need to get rid of the logo field. Unfortunately, I am a beginner, so don't really know where to start. Thanks!